# i am trying to install Cruise control for kafka cluster management but the build is failing due to java error

Tags: java, gradle

```
[root@node3 kafka]# ./gradlew jar
Downloading https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-7.0.2-all.zip
..............10%...............20%...............30%..............40%...............50%...............60%...............70%..............80%...............90%...............100%

Welcome to Gradle 7.0.2!

Here are the highlights of this release:
 - File system watching enabled by default
 - Support for running with and building Java 16 projects
 - Native support for Apple Silicon processors
 - Dependency catalog feature preview

For more details see https://docs.gradle.org/7.0.2/release-notes.html

Starting a Gradle Daemon (subsequent builds will be faster)
<-------------> 0% CONFIGURING [5m 49s]
> root project



<---------
> Configure project :
Starting build with version 3.0.0-SNAPSHOT using Gradle 7.0.2, Java 1.8 and Scala 2.13.6

> Task :generator:compileJava FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':generator:compileJava'.
> Could not load class 'com.sun.tools.javac.api.JavacTool

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
```

Comment: Perhaps you have only a jre available, not a jdk (needed for compiling)?

Comment: [root@node3 cruise-control]# echo $JAVA_HOME
/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.262.b10-1.el7.x86_64/jre
[root@node3 cruise-control]# java -version
openjdk version "1.8.0_262"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_262-b10)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.262-b10, mixed mode)

Comment: FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':cruise-control-core:compileJava
> Could not load class 'com.sun.tools.javac.api.JavacTool

Comment: it works on java 11 platform closing this issue